# Disabling jQuery UI Date Picker Dates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I am trying to disable dates in a jQuery UI Date Picker, it works when I hard code the dates in to the variable in the JS file as follows:

```
var bookedDays = ["2015-3-7","2015-3-8","2015-3-15"];
```

In my PHP file I have:

```
<?php
$testing = "SELECT fromdate, todate FROM messages WHERE listing_id = '".$_GET['listingid']."'";
        $resulttesting = mysql_query($testing) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $testing);
        while ($rowtesting = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttesting)) 
{
    $from = $rowtesting['fromdate'];
    $to = $rowtesting['todate'];

}

$start_time = strtotime($from);
$end_time = strtotime($to);
$date_list = array($from);

$current_time = $start_time;

while($current_time < $end_time) {
    //Add one day
    $current_time += 86400;
    $date_list[] = date('Y-m-d',$current_time);
}
//Finally add end date to list, array contains all dates in order
$date_list[] = $to;
$date_list_res = '["' . implode('","', $date_list) . '"]';

print_r ($date_list_res);

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bookedDays = <?php echo json_encode($date_list_res); ?>;
</script>
```

When I run a console.log in the JS file for the variable bookedDays I get ["2015-03-05","2015-03-06","2015-03-07","2015-03-08","2015-03-08"] output which is read from the database which is correct but these dates are not disabling in the date picker. Does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `2015-03-07 != 2015-3-7` are you sure there isn't some sort of formatting issue here ?

Comment: @adeneo - Good shout, if I change the hard coded dates to var bookedDays = ["2015-03-07","2015-03-08","2015-03-15"]; it doesn't work.

Do you know of any way to strip the 0 off the dates if they begin with 0?

Comment: Worked a treat :D Thanks very much @AlvarFinSoftSoome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<?php echo json_encode($date_list_res); ?>;
```

Type just

```
<?php echo $date_list_res; ?>;
```

Everything should be dandy.

Comment: Tried that but still getting the same issue :(